# How can I updates my records in MYSQL using csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I Have created a table on my db, and filled all the records, using CSV file.
I need to do this weekly to keep the table updated.

I want to upload the new records without disturbing the old one onto the same table using csv.
[I have to pick the data from remote host and upload it locally on my server, i dont have access to the remote db]

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload records from a CSV into a table VERY quickly using the load data infile syntax (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

The syntax is pretty simple, but also flexible. This is an example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE table2
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

You can kick these off from a console or via code.

This will append to the table, not replace it, so if you don't truncate it first, it should work a charm.

You can of course also load the data manually by parsing the CSV file in your code and manually creating an insert statement for each line of code, but if the format is fixed already, this will be quicker and more efficient.

Edit: It appends the data. By default, no database will delete data from a table unless you specifically tell it to. Any insert statement is what you consider an append statement.

Comment: i am only worried abot the current records. if i will upload the new data, will it appened the old data or overwrite ??? I am using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: @user3500806 No problems! Welcome to the site, and as this is your first question, if one of the answers here answers your question, it would be great if you Accept It as this will stop other people trying to answer it again.